# Velodyne VLP 16 plugin

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I'm trying to run Velodyne VLP 16 in gazebo , I want to understand how it works, how many points per second we have, and  and i want to know if the time of the simulation is the same of the real time. So I tried to understand the plugin of Velodyne but I can't find the answers to my question, is there anyone can help?

Thanks for you help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298127/velodyne-vlp-16--plugin/) by [Rihab](https://answers.ros.org/users/34083/rihab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2018-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running in a simulated Velodyne VLP-16 in gazebo, you can check the real time factor. I used it almost an year ago and it ran at 0.3 * time real time, but it will vary depending upon your pc specs. At that point plugin ran on CPU, and around a month ago they released it with gpu support so it would definitely improve real time factor alot.

```
<gazebo reference="${name}_link">
  <sensor type="${sensor_type}" name="VLP16">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <update_rate>10</update_rate>
    <ray>
      <scan>
        <horizontal>
          <samples>360</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-${M_PI}</min_angle>
          <max_angle> ${M_PI}</max_angle>
        </horizontal>
        <vertical>
          <samples>16</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-${15.0*M_PI/180.0}</min_angle>
          <max_angle> ${15.0*M_PI/180.0}</max_angle>
        </vertical>
      </scan>
      <range>
        <min>1.0</min>
        <max>140.0</max>
        <resolution>0.001</resolution>
      </range>
      <noise>
        <type>gaussian</type>
        <mean>0.0</mean>
        <stddev>0.0</stddev>
      </noise>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_velodyne_laser.so">
      <topicName>${ros_topic}</topicName>
      <frameName>${name}_link</frameName>
      <min_range>1.0</min_range>
      <max_range>140.0</max_range>
      <gaussianNoise>0.008</gaussianNoise>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

It's pretty straight forward, beams (samples) along x, along y, M_PI is 3.14, and ranges is between 1-140 m, that's more or less what actual thing has. You can also add noise if you wish.
Hope this answered your question.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2018-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rihab](https://answers.ros.org/users/34083/rihab/) on 2018-07-21**:
so the velodyne vlp 16 uses the clock of our pc ?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-07-22**:
this plugin `libgazebo_ros_velodyne_laser` used clock but as I mentioned they have added functionality to work with gpu [link](https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/velodyne_simulator/src), and it publishes pointcloud. If you use `libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser`, it uses gpu, but outputs laserscan.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-07-22**:
and kindly accept the answer if this served you question.

**Comment by [Rihab](https://answers.ros.org/users/34083/rihab/) on 2018-07-22**:
Ok, thanks .

**Comment by [Kaushal](https://answers.ros.org/users/168032/kaushal/) on 2023-08-03**:
Would 16 channels mean we are able to see 16 layers when we visualize it? I am not able to see anything of the sort in rviz. Just seeing 1 layer of points in RVIZ. Can somebody help?